# Loading an XML file when the tags are written in Greek doesn't work, why?

Tags: c#, xml, unicode, encoding, utf-8

When I load XML files with English tags everything works fine but when I try to load an XML file with tags written in the Greek Language nothing works, why is this happening?
Do I have to change the encoding somewhere in the code?
This is the code I use:

```
 XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
 xdoc.Load(filename);
 XmlNode root = xdoc.DocumentElement;
 if (root.HasChildNodes)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < root.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
            {
                richTextBox1.AppendText(root.ChildNodes[i].InnerXml + "\n");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please provide exact error and sample XML that does not work. "Nothing works" is not useful - i.e. I think sun is still rising wherever your are - so something is working ok :).

Comment: "nothing works" is a very vague description. What happens?

Comment: here is a sample of some xml file I use with Greek characters [link](http://ge.tt/8kcwuYF/v/0?c). And what exactly is happening is that it doesn't seem to recognise the nodes, because it doesn't change line "\n" upon the next tag.

Comment: @chrisdeneb: What do you mean by "doesn't change line '\n'`"?

Comment: inside the richTextBox1, it copies the nodes continuously. Normally it should write the second node to the second row of the richTextBox1 the third to the third line... Also another problem is that it copies both the inner text AND the tag.. which is now happening when the tags a written in English.

Comment: The XML file loads ok for me. Maybe the problem is not in the reading of the XML file but in the behavior of the rich text box when you append XML with Greek tags into it?

Comment: Do you mean something could be wrong in the properties of the rich text box?

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded your file and deserialized/displayed succesfully.

```
public class ΦΑΡΜΑΚΑ
{
    public string A;
    public string ΦΑΡΜ_ΑΓΩΓΗ;
    public string ΧΟΡΗΓΗΣΗ;
    public string ΛΗΞΗΣ;
    public string ΑMKA;
}

XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ΦΑΡΜΑΚΑ[]),new XmlRootAttribute("dataroot"));

ΦΑΡΜΑΚΑ[] array = (ΦΑΡΜΑΚΑ[])xml.Deserialize(File.Open(@"D:\Downloads\bio3.xml", FileMode.Open));

richTextBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, array.Select(x => x.ΦΑΡΜ_ΑΓΩΓΗ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your rich text box has its multiline property set to true. Default is true, but you can may have changed it. Also, instead of \n use Environment.NewLine.

Also .InnerText will get you the value without the tags. InnerXml gives you the markup as well.

Comment: The Environment.NewLine didn't work but thanks for the idea. As far as the InnerXml I know it gives you also the markup it works perfectly when the tags are written in English.